# Can't log in to the DC remotely as Admin

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, domain-controller

I need some assistance ASAP my old IT Manager who got fire mess up our DC. Now I can' login to DC remotely as Administrator. Non of the 5 Windows servers that I have. This is the error message

" To Sign in remotely you need the right to sign in Through Remote Desktop Services. By Default members of the Administrators Group have this right or if the right has been remove from the Administrator group you need to be granted this right manually."

I think he was try to enable remote desktop on all the computers but instead the broke some settings.

Please help on this urgent issue.

Thanks

Comment: Log on locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can login with the local admin account and add your user account to the Domain Admins group and then you will have access to login.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Group Policy to setup the Domain Controllers GPO to reset the local group policy / settings were set directly on the servers.

IF you have Admin right, you should be able to do it.

Johnathan Nguyen